# Remove last element from array if it matches a particular condition

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to remove the last element from an array if it matches a particular value?

For instance:

```
components = dedupeLast(components, '<app-builder-placeholder></app-builder-placeholder>');

function dedupeLast(a, target) {
  for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (i === a.length) {
      if(a[i] === target)
      a.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a `for` loop o.O Your function tries to remove every element that matches `target` but fails so because you're modifying the array.

Comment: @Andreas it doesn't remove anything as the condition `i === a.length` is always false

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Missed that part... But this at least prevents the corruption of the array^^

Comment: invert your `for` to do `i--`  and to start from the `length - 1` element @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: @DevFlamur but that will remove every matching element. OP wants to remove only the last one if it matches.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir then use `pop() ` look here https://alligator.io/js/push-pop-shift-unshift-array-methods/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the last element you're after then you don't need the loop at all, just check if the array is empty or not and access the last element directly:

```
function dedupeLast(a, target) {
   if(a.length && a[a.length - 1] === target){
      a.pop();
   }
}
```

It reads: if `a` is not empty (`a.length != 0`) and the last element `a[a.length - 1] === target` then, remove the last element using `pop`.

Comment: `.splice(a.length - 1, 1)` is the same as `.splice(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pop`, to access last element if it satisfies the criteria remove it else add it again.

```js
function dedupeLast(a, target) {
  
  let temp = a.pop();
  if(temp === target){
    return;
  }
  else{
    a.push(temp);
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since *[array.splice](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12)* creates a new Array and copies the removed elements to it, I would use *array.pop* instead for better performance.

```
function dedupeLast(a, target) {
  let temp;
  if(a.length && a[a.length - 1] === target){
    temp = a.pop();
  }
}
```

[Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) just removes the last element an returns it. If you check before, if that element equals target, there is no need to *pop* and *push*. If you need the removed element for something else, you can just use *temp*.